# Refactoring my loop react component from plain javascript to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

So with the help from stack overflow i managed to create my loop that do exactly what i want in react. It is a functional component.

Now i try to refactoring that loop to typescript and dont understand why i get these errors.

So my DetailedProduct look like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {Container, Image, Jumbotron} from "react-bootstrap"
import testPic from "../941860.png"
import {Product} from "../interfaces/Product"

export const DetailedProduct = ({product}: Product) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Jumbotron fluid>
                    <Image src={testPic} fluid/>
            </Jumbotron>
            <h1>{product.productName}</h1>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

So the problem here is in javascript i can do something like this:

```
export const DetailedProduct = ({product}) => {
return ( <h1>{product.price}<h1/> )
}
```

and i can call that component like this:

```
<DetailedProduct product={product}/>
```

Now with typescript any is ofc not valid. So i tried it with a interface and even that dont work.

It give me this error and i dont know why it is any instead of Product from the Interface.

> Type '{ children: Product; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': id, productName, productDescription, productPricets(2739)

So here is a sandbox i create. Hope you can access it. -> https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-sandbox-questionrefactoring-243rb?file=/src/App.tsx

Thank you for any help again.

Kind of new to react i know typescript and javascript but that jsx is new land for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const DetailedProduct: React.FC<Product> = ({ product }: Product) => {
  return <h1>{product.productName}</h1>;
};
```

React props are an object, with each prop being one property of that object. That means that `<DetailedProduct product={product} />` will receive props of type: `{ product: Product }`.

You also don't need to declare prop types twice (once in `React.FC<Props>` and one in the function arguments).

So if you change the type of your props to `{ product: Product }` it should all work like you expect:

```
export const DetailedProduct: React.FC<{ product: Product }> = ({
  product
}) => {
  return <h1>{product.productName}</h1>;
};
```

Or even more simply:

```
export function DetailedProduct({ product }: { product: Product }) {
  return <h1>{product.productName}</h1>;
}
```

---

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-sandbox-questionrefactoring-forked-06onq)

Comment: so i need to pass the object {} and after that i need a second object? that is the type?

Sry confused here. I know Kotlin for example.
`There is val string1: String or fun test(text: String) {
println("$text")
}`
but even in typescript there is like let text: string but not String. But why the objects? from {}

Sry that i ask for the question i want to understand. And what is preferable const = function or export the function? 

And thank you yes your solution works :-)

Comment: This is just how react props work. `{ product }` destructures the props of type `{ product: Product }`. It makes more sense when you have more than one prop. It's a good convention to declare props as their own interface to make it clearer. See: https://tsplay.dev/9Wv2RW